Can I use an elbow on a tub overflow to clear framing?
I’m installing an alcove tub (Kohler Underscore), and a beam runs under the center of where the specs show the overflow connection to the waste line. The area under tub drain itself is clear.
Is there any reason why I can’t use an elbow where the overflow comes down, install the drain tee in the horizontal section from tub drain, and connect to the waste line there?

A photo or link to your specific plumbing would be great. I'd rather not assume.

Do you mean to Kolher’s drain kit?

Whatever parts we're talking about. A look at the framing situation would also be helpful.

There is no reason in principle, but there are a lot of wrong ways to combine various elbows with drain kits that are not meant to be modular.  I think your question would be better with a specific plan and, as noted, a picture of the framing.   We could tell you what's wrong with the plan, rather than just say the general concept is fine (it is).
